# How to flatten a list of lists of lists in haskell

Tags: haskell, flatten

All I want to do is what I ask. The type signature of the function should be this:

```
flatten::[[[Int]]] -> [[Int]]
```

I tried to search some flatten code but they define new types and that confuses me. Any help?

Comment: [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=[[[Int]]]%20->%20[[Int]]&) helps. ;)

Comment: There are two ways to flatten. Which one do you mean? `[[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]] -> [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]` and `[[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]] -> [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]`

Comment: ^^^ that's `fmap join` vs. `join`.

Comment: @vek Hoogle returns no results. Can you fix the link?

Answer (score 26):

There are (at least) two ways to write

```
flatten::[[[Int]]] -> [[Int]]
```

One is

```
flatten1 = concat
-- Example: flatten [[[1], [2]], [[3]]] = [[1], [2], [3]] :: [[Int]]
```

Another one is

```
flatten2 = map concat
-- Example: flatten [[[1], [2]], [[3]]] = [[1,2], [3]] :: [[Int]]
```

Basically, `flatten1` flattens the "middle" level of brackets, while `flatten2` flattens the "innermost" level of brackets.

As an exercise, you might want to convince yourself that

```
concat . flatten1 = concat . flatten2 :: [[[Int]]] -> [Int]
```

Indeed, both would produce `[1,2,3]` on the example above.

## A more advanced remark

The law above is actually a very famous one, since it is a special case of the monad law

```
join . fmap join = join . join :: Monad m => m (m (m a)) -> m a
```

where `m = []` (i.e., in the list monad), and `a=Int`

Answer (score 20):

You are looking for

```
concat :: [[a]] -> [a]
```

In your use case, the element type happens to be `[Int]`.

Answer (score 2):

One of the best ways to find answers to questions like yours is to use hoogle.  For example see
http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5B%5B%5Ba%5D%5D%5D+-%3E+%5B%5Ba%5D%5D.

The concat function is second in the resulting list.

There is also hayoo: http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html which searches all of hackage.

Comment: Hoogle doesn't find any results.